# How to replace column values in dataframe-js?

Tags: javascript, dataframe, dataframe-js

I have 2 javascript dataframes:

```
    const df1 = new DataFrame([
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    ], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']);
```

and

```
    const df2 = new DataFrame([
        [11, 22, 33, 44, 55], 
        [11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
        [11, 22, 33, 44, 55],
    ], ['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5']);
```

`df1.show(df1.count())` gives:

```
| c1        | c2        | c3        | c4        | c5        |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 2         | 3         | 4         | 5         |
| 1         | 2         | 3         | 4         | 5         |
| 1         | 2         | 3         | 4         | 5         |
```

`df2.show(df2.count())` gives:

```
| c1        | c2        | c3        | c4        | c5        |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 11        | 22        | 33        | 44        | 55        |
| 11        | 22        | 33        | 44        | 55        |
| 11        | 22        | 33        | 44        | 55        |
```

What is the best way to replace all values in columns `c2` and `c3` in `df1` with column values from `df2`?

So eventually i want to end up with:

```
| c1        | c2        | c3        | c4        | c5        |
------------------------------------------------------------
| 1         | 22        | 33         | 4         | 5         |
| 1         | 22        | 33         | 4         | 5         |
| 1         | 22        | 33         | 4         | 5         |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I did it (fast):

```
const cols = ['c2', 'c3']
const values = df2.select(...cols).toArray()

for (i in cols) {
    df1 = df1.withColumn(cols[i], (row, j) => values[j][i])
}
```

Or alternatively (equally fast):

```
const cols = ['c2', 'c3']
const values = df2.select(...cols).toArray()

for (i in cols) {
    df1 = df1.chain((row, j) => row.set(cols[i], values[j][i]))
}
```

Or even shorter (but about 10 times slower):

```
const cols = ['c2', 'c3']

for (i in cols) {
    df1 = df1.withColumn(cols[i], (row, j) => df2.select(cols[i]).toArray()[j][0])
}
```

Is there any easier way to achieve the same?